# Families of curves with "almost-general" moduli

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hilbert-schemes

The Brill-Noether theorem says that, if $\rho(d, g, r) := (r + 1)d - rg - r(r + 1) \geq 0$, then there exists a unique component of the Hilbert scheme of curves of degree $d$ and genus $g$ in $\mathbb{P}^r$ which dominates $M_g$.

Is it true that all the other components of the Hilbert scheme have "small" image in $M_g$?

For example (under the hypothesis $\rho(d, g, r) \geq 0$), is it true that there is no other component of the Hilbert scheme whose image in moduli is, say, of codimension 1? Of codimension 2? Of codimension less than r?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I only now noticed it.  I do not know why you say that the Brill-Noether theorem implies that there is a unique component of the Hilbert scheme that dominates the moduli space.  For instance, when $g>4$, when $d=2g-2$, and when $r=g-1$, then there is, indeed, a unique irreducible component of $\text{Hilb}^{dt+1-g}_{\mathbb{P}^r_k/k}$ that dominates moduli space and whose generic point parameterizes a smooth, canonically embedded, genus $g$ curve.  However, there is another irreducible component that dominates moduli, whose generic point parameterizes an embedded, genus $g$ curve of degree $d=2g-2$ such that the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(1)$ is not the canonical bundle, and such that the linear span of the curve is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^r_k$.

The Hilbert scheme parameterizes all manner of closed subschemes, including smooth, embedded curves that are linearly degenerate.  Perhaps you want to add a hypothesis that you consider only the open subset of the Hilbert scheme that parameterizes smooth, embedded, linearly nondegenerate curves.