# An analogue of Brill-Noether for hypersurfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes, brill-noether

Let $d,g,r$ be natural numbers such that $d \geq 1$, $g \geq 2$, $r \geq 3$. Denote by $\mathcal{H}_{d,g,r}$ the Hilbert scheme classifying subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^r$ with Hilbert polynomial $P(x) = d  x + (1 - g)$. There is a natural rational map from any component of $\mathcal{H}_{d,g,r}$ whose general member is a smooth curve to the moduli of curves $\mathcal{M}_g$.

The fundamental result of Brill-Noether theory asserts that there exists such a component that dominates $\mathcal{M}_g$ if and only if the Brill-Noether number, defined by the formula
\begin{equation}
\rho(d, g, r) := (r + 1)d - r g - r(r + 1)
\end{equation}
is non-negative.

**My question is:** are there any reasonable conditions one can be imposed on the curve, the line bundle, the  $\mathfrak{g}^r_d$ etc to insure that the natural forgetful map from the flag-Hilbert scheme parametrizing curves embedded in degree $e$ hypersurfaces $C \subset X \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ to the Brill-Noether component in the Hilbert scheme of curves is dominant? (more generally, what about complete intersections?)

Comment: It is not true that Brill-Noether theory implies that when there exists at least one component $\mathcal{H}_{d,g,r}$ dominating $\mathcal{M}_g$, then this component is unique.  I already addressed this in a previous MO answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178822/families-of-curves-with-almost-general-moduli

Comment: corrected. Though out of curiousity - as you said in the previous question: it is true if I add "smooth, embedded, linearly nondegenerate curves", right?

Comment: Yes, it is true if you add "linearly nondegenerate" to the hypotheses for a general member of $\mathcal{H}_{d,g,r}$.

Comment: Your question appears to be asking the following: for a general curve $C$, and for a general $\mathfrak{g}^r_d$ on that curve, say $\phi:C\to \mathbb{P}^r$ (let's assume $r\geq 3$ so that $\phi$ is an embedding), for the ideal sheaf $I$ of $\phi(C)\subset \mathbb{P}^r$, for which $e>0$ is $h^0(\mathbb{P}^r,I(e))$ positive?  Of course if $e> 2(g-1)/d$, then $h^0(\mathbb{P}^r,I(e)) \geq \binom{r+e}{r} - (ed + 1 -g)$.

Comment: @Jason: thanks again! But if I understand correctly - your answer explains when a specific curve is contained in a hypersurface of degree $e$, but what about the deformation theory? i.e. this is probably a naive question, but why is it obvious you can choose these hypersurfaces to vary in a flat family?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  By generic flatness, every finite type morphism with target $\mathcal{G}_d^r$ (or $\mathcal{W}_d^r$ if you  prefer) is flat over a dense Zariski open of the unique irreducible component that dominates $\mathcal{M}_g$.

Comment: Here is what I'm asking (btw it is completely possible that for an algebraic geometer this is trivial): I pick a general curve with a general $\mathfrak{g}^r_d$ with $r \geq 3$ which is contained in a smooth complete intersection of multidegree $(e_1,\ldots,e_m)$. What conditions do I need to impose so that any other general curve with a general $\mathfrak{g}^r_d$ is contained in a smooth complete intersection of multidegree $(e_1,\ldots,e_m)$. I also want to make sure that these complete intersections can vary smoothly (i.e., in a flat family over an open subset of $\mathcal{M}_g$).

Comment: What I'm worried about is the possibility of having a curve contained in a hypersurface/complete intersection and being unable to extend it to nearby curves. So I was wondering if that's a deformation theory problem (i.e., we deform the abstract curve, then we need to make sure that there exists a possibility to lift it to the deformation of the embedded curve, then we need to check the hypersurface/complete intersections deforms as well, and that there exists such a deformation that contains a deformation of the embedded curve).

Comment: @JasonStarr Again, I believe there should be some kind of deformation sequence that shows this. It is probably obvious for an algebraic geometer... but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: There are obstructions to deforming individual curves.  However, there is a powerful, foundational theorem in algebraic geometry -- the "Generic Flatness Theorem" -- that guarantees that for every finite type morphism whose target is Noetherian and reduced, there exists a dense open subset of the target over which the morphism is flat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55634/discussion-between-nati-and-jason-starr).